# What is the equivalent of a twig template form action={{path('page')}} in a php template

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm doing a project for a client and most of the templating is already page.html.php templates, I'm used to twig, I haven't found this info anywhere but how would you do the same below for a php template.

```
 <form method=post action={{path('page')}}>
```

I tried

```
 action=$views['routes']->generate('page');
```

but this does nothing, it works for links fine.

What's the correct way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo $view['router']->generate('page') ?>
```

Documentation is here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#generating-urls-from-a-template